# Uploading an API to a port on a DigitalOcean droplet port

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5, digital-ocean

I'm not sure if I used the correct jargon, but I hope my question is clear. I am trying to upload an API, I made using Laravel to a port on my DigitalOcean droplet.

Basically, when I connect to `***.***.***.***:port` I want it to connect to my API.

I have made a `.conf` file for my api which is below:

```
Listen ***.***.***.***:8037
<VirtualHost ***.***.***.***:8037>
ServerName www.name.lk
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/hotelguide/public"
<Directory /var/www/html/hotelguide/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This file is placed in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

I used 8037 as a random port.

I read up on this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html as this seems to contain what I want, but when I edit `etc/apache2/ports.conf` and I add `Listen 8037` and I restart the service.

But then I visit `***.***.***.***:8037` and I get a Forbidden 403 error.

**UPDATE**:
I followed through with what @katie answered. And I still seem to be getting the Forbidden 403 error. These are the results of `nmap` and `netstat`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a Virtual Host directive that works:

```
<VirtualHost *:8037>

        #ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/hotelguide/public"
...
</VirtualHost>
```

I took out the `ServerName` directive (it is commented out with the #), as it wasn't necessary, and seemed to actually break it.  If it is the only app you want running on that port, then you don't have to drill down further using `ServerName` matches. I have used `ServerName` with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/path/to/website in the past, but that only seems to work with port 80.

Lastly, make sure you have opened port 8037 on your firewall.

And one last side note, you have the Listen 8037 as if you have that in your sites-available conf, but you don't need it in there (just in the ports.conf as you mentioned later).

Then to get to your app, you type xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8037 and it should go to your `DocumentRoot`.

**Update**

With your setup (I changed to port 8037), and apache is clearly working, (when I bring up xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8037, the website I set up comes up in my browser),

You can do `netstat -ant` on your Digital Ocean server and you should see:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8037                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Also, I caused the forbidden error when I changed the permissions on the /var/www files.  The best permissions are 750 for directories and 640 for files, here are the lines you can execute in a .sh file to accomplish that permission setup:

```
sudo find /var/www -exec chown root:www-data {} \;
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod -v 750 {} \;
sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod -v 640 {} \;
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. I did exactly as you suggested and I still seem to be getting the Forbidden 403 error :( Could you please look at the above update I posted to my question. Thanks again

Comment: @user9492428 See the update to my post, hope it helps!

Comment: @user9492428 So glad to hear it!